# JPA does not create composite tables in a local postgreSQL Database

Tags: java, postgresql, eclipselink, persistence, jpa-2.0

so until now I have used a remote server and database and JPA has always created those tables:

[image: tables in remote database]

but now I have to do something in a local PostgreSQL database and JPA creates only the Entities:
[image: tables in local database]

I run the same code. The only thing I have changed is the persistance unit in the Entitimanagerfactory.
Do you guys have any idea why this happens?
Also... I am not posting any code since I don't know where the issue might be and I don't want to post my entire program.

Edit:

```java
  @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Question.class, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinTable(name = "test",
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "gameId", referencedColumnName = "gameId"),
      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "questionId", referencedColumnName = "questionId"),
      uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"questionId", "gameId"})
  )
  private List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<>();
```

```java
  @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Game.class, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinTable( name = "test",
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "questionId", referencedColumnName = "questionId"),
      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "gameId", referencedColumnName = "gameId"),
      uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"questionId", "gameId"})
  )
  private List<Game> game = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Well it seems like you have an idea what it could be - revert your changes until the program works again and then post the code that breaks it

Comment: the persistance unit properties in both the local and remote unit are the same except one goes outside and the other one goes to local.

Comment: What kind of relation do you have between 'game' and 'question'  entities. Please list the corresponded code from both sides of the relation.

Comment: Table creation is controlled through persistence properties, both JPA and provider specifics - show us what you've defined, where and how you are trying to get it created. Turn on logging within EclipseLink as it may give you a clue, or at least something to compare the working logs against the non-working ones.